# Reshaping list of tensors in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, keras, concatenation, reshape

How do I pass input to concatenate layer such when it is passed to TimeDistributed layer, I should get a output shape of (None, 1, 1536) instead of (None, 32, 1536)?

```
input_shape = (32, 32, 32, 4)
cnn_count = 5

def create_cnn_lstm_model():

    model = create_shared_weight_cnn()

    for i in range(cnn_count):
        temp_name_input = 'input_' + str(i)
        globals()[temp_name_input] = Input(shape=input_shape)

    combined_input = []
    for i in range(cnn_count):
        temp_name_input = 'input_' + str(i)
        combined_input.append(globals()[temp_name_input])

    seq = concatenate(combined_input)
    out = TimeDistributed(Lambda(lambda x: model(combined_input)))(seq)
    out = LSTM(512)(out)
    out = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(out)

    cnn_lstm = Model(inputs=combined_input, outputs=out)

    return cnn_lstm
```

Comment: What are the shapes of all the tensors inside combined_input?

Comment: combined_input is a list which contains 5 tensors each of shape (?, 32, 32, 32, 4)